# Convert ASCII to hex

Tags: string, flutter, dart, hex

I want convert ASCII values to hex. In Java, I often use the function:

```
private static String asciiToHex(String asciiStr) {
    char[] chars = asciiStr.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : chars) {
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) ch));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}
```

Is there any method in Dart to convert to hex value like `Integer.toHexString` in Java?

**Example:**

```
youtube.com
```

**Output**

```
796F75747562652E636F6D
```

Comment: `import 'package:convert/convert.dart';    print(hex.encode('youtube.com'.codeUnits));` - for more see https://pub.dev/packages/convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `Integer.toHexString` would be to call [.toRadixString(16)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/int/toRadixString.html) on an integer value.

The `asciiToHex` function can be translated to dart like so:

```dart
String asciiToHex(String asciiStr) {
  List<int> chars = asciiStr.codeUnits;
  StringBuffer hex = StringBuffer();
  for (int ch in chars) {
    hex.write(ch.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0'));
  }
  return hex.toString();
}
```

Comment: You should use `.padLeft(2, '0')` too so that the string is parsable if there are values in the range [0x0, 0xF].

Comment: @jamesdlin good point. Updated to include `padLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String hexToAscii(String hexString) => List.generate(
      hexString.length ~/ 2,
      (i) => String.fromCharCode(
          int.parse(hexString.substring(i * 2, (i * 2) + 2), radix: 16)),
    ).join();
```